# How to use AVG after using COUNT and GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL

I have `orders` table, and I want to average the number of orders from specific item per month in the past years.

So for example if item #50 was ordered 20 times in 2021-04, and 40 times in 2020-04, I need to calculate the average which would be 30.

Assuming the table structure is:

```
id | item_number | order_date
```

I got the first part of the COUNT:

```
 SELECT item_number, COUNT(item_number) AS count
 FROM orders
 WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 4
 GROUP BY item_number, MONTH(order_date), YEAR(order_date)
```

I was not able to make the average per item per month so far.

*I am not even sure I need to do the COUNT step as I do above since it's all in the same table? But I am not sure

Comment: yes I'm deleting the other one, it had too many errors and confused people. Edit: oh I can't

Comment: what if it was ordered 20 times in 2020-04, 0 times in 2021-04, and 40 times in 2022-04?  Do you want 20 then or 30?  If 20, are you ok with not counting years before it was first ordered in that month or after it was last ordered in that month?  Or is there some way besides the orders table to tell what span of years to average for?

Comment: Good point, so far I believe I ignored missing years, and I believe the answer that matches that logic is the one I chose below. Do you know what I should do in order to count years without orders at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your query into a subquery, then do the average in the main query.

```
SELECT item_number, AVG(count) AS avg_count
FROM (
    SELECT item_number, COUNT(item_number) AS count
    FROM orders
    WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 4
    GROUP BY item_number, MONTH(order_date), YEAR(order_date)
) AS x
GROUP BY item_number
```

Comment: It worked! Do you have any idea though why it shows the column as `AVG(count)` instead of the alias `x`?

Comment: @Pelegrino x is an alias for the subquery change `AVG(count)` to `AVG(count) as tot_count` or anything you want

Comment: @ErgestBasha ty, from some reason when I tried earlier it gave me a syntax error. Tried now again and it worked, I guess I had a typo